# Latex Tikz/Pgf declaring shapes with parameters and anchors with numbers

Tags: parameters, latex, tikz, pgf

I am writing some shapes in pgf and i don't really know everything about how this works but i managed to get through the documentation.

```latex
\pgfdeclareshape{reg}{
  % The 'minimum width' and 'minimum height' keys, not the content, determine
  % the size
  \savedanchor\northeast{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
    \pgf@x=0.11\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=0.15\pgf@y
  }
  % This is redundant, but makes some things easier:
  \savedanchor\southwest{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
    \pgf@x=-0.11\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=-0.15\pgf@y
  }
  % Inherit from rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]

  % Define same anchor a normal rectangle has
  \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
  \anchor{north}{\northeast \pgf@x=0pt}
  \anchor{east}{\northeast \pgf@y=0pt}
  \anchor{south}{\southwest \pgf@x=0pt}
  \anchor{west}{\southwest \pgf@y=0pt}
  \anchor{north east}{\northeast}
  \anchor{north west}{\northeast \pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
  \anchor{south west}{\southwest}
  \anchor{south east}{\southwest \pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
  \anchor{text}{
    \pgfpointorigin
    \advance\pgf@x by -.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by -.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by +.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
  }

  % Define anchors for signal ports

  \anchor{CLK}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@x=0\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=1\pgf@y%
  }
  \anchor{PC}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@x=-2.5\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=0\pgf@y%
  }

  \anchor{PCS}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@x=2.5\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=0\pgf@y%
  }

  % Draw the rectangle box and the port labels
  \backgroundpath{
    % Rectangle box
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}

    % Drawing Triangle for clock input
    % upper left x
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x 
    \northeast \pgf@ya=\pgf@y \pgf@yb=\pgf@y \pgf@xb=\pgf@x
    \pgf@anchor@reg@CLK
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@x \pgf@yc=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{1.3ex}
    \advance\pgf@xa by .15mm
    \advance\pgf@xb by -.15mm
    \advance\pgf@yc by -\pgf@x
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
    \pgfclosepath


    \tikzset{flip flop/port labels} % Use font from this style
    \tikz@textfont



    %Drawing CLK circuit
    \pgf@anchor@reg@CLK
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{1.8ex}
    \advance\pgf@yb by \pgf@x
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    %Draw clock label
    \pgf@anchor@reg@CLK\pgftext[base,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}]{\raisebox{2.5ex}{CLK}}

    %Drawing PC circuit
    \pgf@anchor@reg@PC
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y \pgf@yb=\pgf@y \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \pgf@anchor@reg@west
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x 
    %\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{2.7ex}
    %\advance\pgf@xb by \pgf@x
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgf@anchor@reg@PC\pgftext[base,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x+0.5ex}{\pgf@y}}]{\raisebox{.5ex}{PC}}

    %Drawing PC' circuit
    \pgf@anchor@reg@PCS
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y \pgf@yb=\pgf@y\pgf@xa=\pgf@x 
    \pgf@anchor@reg@east
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x 
    %\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{2.5ex}
    %\advance\pgf@xb by \pgf@x
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgf@anchor@reg@PCS\pgftext[base,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}]{\raisebox{.5ex}{PC'}}
  }

}
```

Here i created a shape with some connection points on the outside, and it actually works great. But i really want to have a parameter when i create this shape so that i can specify the amount of ports.

For example like this

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [reg,black!50,ports=3] (PC) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But i can't find something in the documentation that allows for custom parameters. Also i wanted to name the anchors A1,A2 and A3 but i can't seem to add numbers in the names, even if in the documentation it explicitly says names like "1" and "::" should be no problem but still "A1" is.

If someone has any idea on how to do this i appreciate the help. And maybe some better references for creating shapes with pgf.

For editing the tex files i use Overleaf with pdflatex.

Edit:
I now found out you can use `\pgfkeys` to add parameters to the shapes, but they don't seem to work right and i don't really know what to with that.

```
\def\microarchbasekey{/tikz/microarch}
\pgfkeys{\microarchbasekey/.is family}

\pgfdeclareshape{mux}{

    \pgfkeys{\microarchbasekey,inputs/.initial=2,spacing/.initial=5}

    \savedmacro{\numpins}{
        \def\numpins{\pgfkeysvalueof{\microarchbasekey/inputs}}
    }

    \saveddimen{\spacing}{
        \pgf@x = \pgfkeysvalueof{\microarchbasekey/spacing}
    }

%a lot of code down there
}
```

but it gives me the following error

```
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

but i can't find the missing part of the code.

Comment: I have zero time now, but you could find interesting the definition of `muxdemux` in `circuitikz`: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/blob/master/tex/pgfcircmultipoles.tex --- it's not so heavily commented but there are a lot of techniques for anchors there.

Comment: i found some things in the github repo and added them to the post. But im struggling to get it to work. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I posted my method --- maybe there are better ways to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably this is a question better suited for the [TeX/LaTeX site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions), but anyway...

The key things are the following:

1. Add keys for the parameters. Be careful about the hierarchy, `node` expects keys under the `/tikz` family:

   ```latex
   %
   % better to create a family, but as an example...
   \tikzset{flip flop/port labels/.initial={\tiny}}
   %
   % number of ports
   \tikzset{ports/.initial=4}
   %
   % we need a counter
   \newcount\tmp@a
   ```
2. Add stable (linked to the specific node, and not to the generic shape) parameters, all those you need to compute the position of the anchors:

   ```latex
   % you have to save the relevant parameters as \savedmacro
       \savedmacro\numports{
           \edef\numports{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ports}}%
       }
       % and \saveddimen
       \saveddimen\pinsdelta{
           % you can't use savedmacros nor savedanchors here (bummer!)
           \edef\numports{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ports}}%
           \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{0.22*\pgfshapeminheight/(\numports+1)}%
       }
   ```
3. In the shape definition, you have to add the anchors with a trick --- anchors have to be added to the shape internal function. Dangerous, because the developers can change it in the future (it happened already), but I know no other way.

   ```latex
   % create input anchors
       % this touch internal things, so beware...
       % anchors are named pgf@anchor@<name-of-the-shape>@<name of the anchors>
       \pgfutil@g@addto@macro\pgf@sh@s@reg{%
           \tmp@a=\numports\relax
           \pgfmathloop%
           \ifnum\pgfmathcounter>\tmp@a%
           \else%
           % assign the anchor "in \pgfmathcounter" to the macro \reg@port with the number as argument
           \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@anchor@reg@in \pgfmathcounter\endcsname{%
               \noexpand\reg@port{\pgfmathcounter}% defined below
           }%
           % \typeout{YAY\space\pgfmathcounter}
           \repeatpgfmathloop%
       }
   ```
4. Define the specific functions that calculate the variable anchors. You must use only `\saved...` kind of parameters here,  otherwise, your anchors will use the last value of the parameter, not the correct one specified with the node.

   ```latex
   \def\reg@port#1{%
       % this macro has the function to return the position of the anchor
       % it must use only \savedanchors and \savedmacros
       % the parameter is the number of the anchor (see above)
       \northeast
       \pgf@x=-\pgf@x
       \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
       \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\pgf@ya-(#1+0.5)*\pinsdelta}%
   }
   ```

Now, I do not understand exactly how you draw your shape so the anchors are not exactly where they should go, but well:

[image: Output]

My full code is here:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
%
% better to create a family, but as an example...
\tikzset{flip flop/port labels/.initial={\tiny}}
%
% number of ports
\tikzset{ports/.initial=4}
%
% we need a counter
\newcount\tmp@a

\pgfdeclareshape{reg}{

    % you have to save the relevant parameters as \savedmacro
    \savedmacro\numports{
        \edef\numports{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ports}}%
    }
    % and \saveddimen
    \saveddimen\pinsdelta{
        % you can't use savedmacros nor savedanchors here (bummer!)
        \edef\numports{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ports}}%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{0.22*\pgfshapeminheight/(\numports+1)}%
    }

    % The 'minimum width' and 'minimum height' keys, not the content, determine
    % the size
    \savedanchor\northeast{%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
        \pgf@x=0.11\pgf@x
        \pgf@y=0.15\pgf@y
    }
    % This is redundant, but makes some things easier:
    \savedanchor\southwest{%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
        \pgf@x=-0.11\pgf@x
        \pgf@y=-0.15\pgf@y
    }
    % Inherit from rectangle
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]

    % Define same anchor a normal rectangle has
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    \anchor{north}{\northeast \pgf@x=0pt}
    \anchor{east}{\northeast \pgf@y=0pt}
    \anchor{south}{\southwest \pgf@x=0pt}
    \anchor{west}{\southwest \pgf@y=0pt}
    \anchor{north east}{\northeast}
    \anchor{north west}{\northeast \pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
    \anchor{south west}{\southwest}
    \anchor{south east}{\southwest \pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
    \anchor{text}{
        \pgfpointorigin
        \advance\pgf@x by -.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y by -.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y by +.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    }

    % Define anchors for signal ports

    \anchor{CLK}{
        \pgf@process{\northeast}%
        \pgf@x=0\pgf@x%
        \pgf@y=1\pgf@y%
    }
    \anchor{PC}{
        \pgf@process{\northeast}%
        \pgf@x=-2.5\pgf@x%
        \pgf@y=0\pgf@y%
    }

    \anchor{PCS}{
        \pgf@process{\northeast}%
        \pgf@x=2.5\pgf@x%
        \pgf@y=0\pgf@y%
    }

    % Draw the rectangle box and the port labels
    \backgroundpath{
        % Rectangle box
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}

        % Drawing Triangle for clock input
        % upper left x
        \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
        \northeast \pgf@ya=\pgf@y \pgf@yb=\pgf@y \pgf@xb=\pgf@x
        \pgf@anchor@reg@CLK
        \pgf@xc=\pgf@x \pgf@yc=\pgf@y
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{1.3ex}
        \advance\pgf@xa by .15mm
        \advance\pgf@xb by -.15mm
        \advance\pgf@yc by -\pgf@x
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
        \pgfclosepath


        \tikzset{flip flop/port labels} % Use font from this style
        \tikz@textfont



        %Drawing CLK circuit
        \pgf@anchor@reg@CLK
        \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
        \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{1.8ex}
        \advance\pgf@yb by \pgf@x
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
        %Draw clock label
        \pgf@anchor@reg@CLK\pgftext[base,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}]{\raisebox{2.5ex}{CLK}}

        %Drawing PC circuit
        \pgf@anchor@reg@PC
        \pgf@ya=\pgf@y \pgf@yb=\pgf@y \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
        \pgf@anchor@reg@west
        \pgf@xb=\pgf@x
        %\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{2.7ex}
        %\advance\pgf@xb by \pgf@x
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgf@anchor@reg@PC\pgftext[base,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x+0.5ex}{\pgf@y}}]{\raisebox{.5ex}{PC}}

        %Drawing PC' circuit
        \pgf@anchor@reg@PCS
        \pgf@ya=\pgf@y \pgf@yb=\pgf@y\pgf@xa=\pgf@x
        \pgf@anchor@reg@east
        \pgf@xb=\pgf@x
        %\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{2.5ex}
        %\advance\pgf@xb by \pgf@x
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgf@anchor@reg@PCS\pgftext[base,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}]{\raisebox{.5ex}{PC'}}
    }

    % create input anchors
    % this touch internal things, so beware...
    % anchors are named pgf@anchor@<name-of-the-shape>@<name of the anchors>
    \pgfutil@g@addto@macro\pgf@sh@s@reg{%
        \tmp@a=\numports\relax
        \pgfmathloop%
        \ifnum\pgfmathcounter>\tmp@a%
        \else%
        % assign the anchor "in \pgfmathcounter" to the macro \reg@port with the number as argument
        \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@anchor@reg@in \pgfmathcounter\endcsname{%
            \noexpand\reg@port{\pgfmathcounter}% defined below
        }%
        % \typeout{YAY\space\pgfmathcounter}
        \repeatpgfmathloop%
    }

}
%
\def\reg@port#1{%
    % this macro has the function to return the position of the anchor
    % it must use only \savedanchors and \savedmacros
    % the parameter is the number of the anchor (see above)
    \northeast
    \pgf@x=-\pgf@x
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\pgf@ya-(#1+0.5)*\pinsdelta}%
}
\makeatother

%%% handy macro to show the anchors

\def\showcoord(#1)<#2:#3>{%
    node[circle, red, draw, inner sep=1pt,pin={%
        [red, inner sep=0.5pt, font=\small,
        pin distance=#3cm, pin edge={red, }%
    ]#2:#1}](#1){}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw,reg,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=3cm, black!50] (PC1) at (0,0) {};
    \path (PC1.north west) \showcoord(NW)<45:0.2>;
    \node [draw, reg,black!50,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=5cm, ports=6, blue] (PC2) at (3,0) {};
    \foreach \p in {1,...,4} \path(PC1.in \p) \showcoord(in \p)<145:0.3>;
    \foreach \p in {1,...,6} \path(PC2.in \p) \showcoord(in \p)<145:0.3>;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Still struggling a lot with all of this, but it seems to work even if i don't completely understand why it does. Is there like a documentation or a site you can recommend looking this up? (Not the tikz/pgf docs) + thanks a lot for taking the time to do this writeup

Comment: @MrDiver not any that I know, apart for the source code. I learned it thanks to the community in the TeX.stackexchange specific site, there are lot of expert and friendly people (and package's authors and even core developers) there!